# Disable Screenshot Security

Tags: security, screenshots

Some apps don't allow screenshots so how can I still take a screenshot?

It is my phone and I should be able to do whatever I want with it so why is there even a feature to disallow screenshots?

Android 5.0.1

Comment: It doesn't matter what app it is (an online shopping app and an online banking app) it is the fact that apps have some kind of control of some features of my OS, what's next? Disallowing internet connection while having an app opened?

Comment: Go to setting and dont allow the app to control that permition

Comment: I can't edit the apps permissions nor is there such a permission for this type of control.

Comment: @Pali You'll have to play by the book unless you root your phone.

Comment: @SarpSTA well then I have found the final reason to root it ;)

Comment: Is it safe to say that all of the answers here require root?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

## Note: this answer is a bit outdated as of August 31, 2022. Will try to update it soon.

#### Why apps prevent screen capturing, and how to disable the restriction

Some apps present sensitive data (e.g. banking apps) or copyright-protected content (e.g. video streaming apps). App developers can opt to use the Android platform’s `FLAG_SECURE` setting to prevent the screen from being captured, recorded, or shown on “non-secure displays” such as the recent apps view. There are a couple of ways to disable this flag:

1. [Smali Patcher](https://forum.xda-developers.com/apps/magisk/module-smali-patcher-0-7-t3680053) module for Magisk. [Magisk](https://github.com/topjohnwu/Magisk) is officially supported on Android versions 4.2⁠–⁠12.0.
2. [DisableFlagSecure](http://repo.xposed.info/module/fi.veetipaananen.android.disableflagsecure) module for Xposed. [Xposed](https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=3034811) is officially supported on Android versions 5.0⁠–⁠8.1.

The Smali Patcher method requires you to connect your phone to a PC and run a Windows program to actually generate the module. Note that Magisk on Android 4.2 does not support MagiskHide.

The Xposed method has a big caveat: many banking apps use Google’s SafetyNet platform for checking device integrity, and prevent the application from being used on devices that have Xposed installed. This renders the module useless in SafetyNet-enabled apps, and there is currently no way to hide Xposed from SafetyNet.

**Use these modules with caution, as they disable the flag *system-wide*.**

#### Taking a screen capture of your phone on your PC

If you can’t or don’t want to disable `FLAG_SECURE` on your phone, you can also use [scrcpy](https://github.com/Genymobile/scrcpy). It lets you mirror your phone’s display to your computer, and then you can just use a screenshot software of your choice on your computer to capture the phone’s screen. This requires you to turn on ADB debugging from your phone’s development settings, but beware that some apps restrict their functions when they detect that development settings are enabled. Scrcpy works on Android versions 5.0–12.0.

Answer (score 5):

You can use [Scrcpy](https://github.com/Genymobile/scrcpy) or [Vysor](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/vysor/gidgenkbbabolejbgbpnhbimgjbffefm) app and project your android screen to computer screen and then take screenshot on your PC.

Comment: I tried this and it did not work. Basically, since you are "casting" your screen through the Vysor app, screenshots will not work.

Comment: You have to take screenshots in your PC, not on mobile

Comment: On your PC you will get a black screen because Android determines that your app is using FLAG_SECURE. So that does not help. You clearly haven't tried this.

Comment: i have tried this with an app, which had screenshot disabled. It doesn't matter, whether the app is using FLAG_SECURE or not, the screen will get projected for sure

Comment: I can confirm that on Marshmallow this app does NOT work for secure apps at all.

Comment: TeamViewer would be another option to accomplish the same thing. Install the [host app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.teamviewer.host.market) on your phone, then connect to it from your PC and take a screenshot of your PC screen.

Comment: I can confirm that I have used the TeamViewer Host app mentioned by @July.Tech to take a screenshot of an app that prevented direct screenshot on the phone. This was done on the Samsung Note 8 running Android 9.

Comment: @Hritik I can confirm that scrcpy works. I also had the problem that Vysor shows a black screen on my laptop but scrcpy always showed the screen and had no black screen issues with it.

Answer (score 3):

There's also [Smali Patcher](https://forum.xda-developers.com/apps/magisk/module-smali-patcher-0-7-t3680053) program for Windows which creates custom Magisk module for your device and has option to disable `FLAG_SECURE` system-wide.

Answer (score 2):

Apps which are set with LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE flag do not allow screenshots (or videos recording) to be taken. It is of-course your phone but the app belongs to its owner (and he can rightfully wish to prevent users from capturing something sensitive in nature). You're barred from taking a screenshot only for those screens that have the above flag set. However you can still take a screenshot by projecting your phone on the PC screen and capturing it. That way, the device has no idea that screenshot is taken.

Comment: How does one project a "phone on the PC screen" and then capture it? Can you clarify if you are implying use of a separate or multiple different applications? Thanks.

Comment: "However you can still take a screenshot by projecting your phone on the PC screen and capturing it. That way, the device has no idea that screenshot is taken." That is missing a crucial aspect: Taking a screenshot should be a nearly instantaneous operation that should NOT require the use of a secondary device to aid the taking of a screenshot.

Comment: This answer is flase. For apps that use the FLAG_SECURE there is no way to project the app to another screen because the app won't allow it.

Comment: I have encountered this for LastPass. I don't see a reason why you would want to take a screenshot of one of your own passwords in-app. It actually holds your hand so you don't fuck up your own security.

Comment: "he can rightfully prevent wish to prevent users..." - I don't really care about his wishes. He doesn't have a legal right to prevent me (eg. It's not illegal to take a photo of my phone with another phone). Besides, lots of apps use FLAG_SECURE even when there is no sensitive data on the screen.

Answer (score 2):

Just for those guys who came here by error in Chrome Incognito mode

**Can't take screenshot due to error policy**

There is a special flag `Incognito screenshots` that can be accessed via

```
chrome://flags
```

The default value is disabled but if you enable it, you are done. Screenshots are allowed.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In some banks you must log in first and disable security measures in regards to mobile applications. I did it with my bank.

Answer (score 1):

I've found a workaround: from the app that is blocking screenshots press the Home button/gesture and then the Recents button/gesture so you can see the app you want to screenshot; you can then screenshot with the normal button shortcut or the on-screen "screenshot" button (and the resulting screenshot will not be blacked-out).

This worked for an over-zealous app which didn't want me screenshotting a specific screen but not for a well-made app (i.e. a browser in incognito mode), so it's almost certainly an exploit that might be patched rather than intended behaviour. Tested on android 9 and 12.

Answer (score 0):

Following on from 'user's' answer, using a program such as Droid@screen [droid at screen](http://droid-at-screen.org/download.html) will allow you to project your phone screen to the PC, and then screenshot it via the PC Prnt Scrn button.

UPDATE:
Android screen mirror is a better and faster screen mirror

https://github.com/adakoda/android-screen-monitor