# How take a screenshot without rooting the phone?

Tags: screenshots

[Disable Screenshot Security](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/133022/13886) implies that I must root my device in order to bypass this unreasonable restriction. I have many use cases where I need to take screenshots for normal,  non-nefarious reasons, yet it seems that I am prevented from doing so by some particuler application provider.

How do I avoid this restriction without rooting my phone?

References:

The following sums up my situation and hardware configuration to the letter:
http://www.netdip.com/unable-capture-screenshot-1464017054/

Comment: You don't. The whole point of that security flag is to prevent bad apps from stealing your private info and only the app developer knows when that will be appearing on the screen. Now if the app developer has set it up even though its a tip calculator - well use a different tip calculator, or root your phone or connect the phone to a PC and use adb/Android Studio: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/138778/how-can-i-take-on-device-screenshots-of-secure-apps

Comment: Alright. then, why does blocking bad apps also require blocking the end-user from using the screenshot facility?

Comment: I'm guessing that `FLAG_SECURE` was originally for DRM. It was only later that the buttons were assigned for user initiated screenshot: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/1759/how-to-take-a-screenshot-with-an-android-device . I expect that the original function was left in, but with an actual API to screencap a device the flag is now valuable for blocking private content

Comment: [Secure surfaces are used to prevent content rendered into those surfaces by applications from appearing in screenshots or from being viewed on non-secure displays.](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Display.html#FLAG_SECURE)- is for your security

Comment: In the scenario I encountered, the LastPass browser was the only application I encountered that was blocking me from taking screenshots. The solution that did not require rooting was LastPass's support: 'You can enable taking a screenshot of the LastPass app/browser by going to LastPass menu> Settings> Security and look for "Allow screenshots of this app".'  However the comment responses here are useful for future reference, so thanks!