# Chrome 65 doesn't allow screenshots in Incognito mode

Tags: chrome-for-android, screenshots

Seems that in Chrome for Android [version 65](https://blog.chromium.org/2018/02/chrome-65-beta-css-paint-api-and.html), a "feature" was introduced which doesn't allow you to take a screenshot in Incognito mode.

When attempting to take a screenshot, Android will now show an alert saying "Taking screenshots isn't allowed by the app or your organization."

```
     /**
     * Sets the attributes flags to secure if there is an incognito tab visible.
     */
    @VisibleForTesting
    void updateIncognitoState() {
        WindowManager.LayoutParams attributes = mWindow.getAttributes();
        boolean currentSecureState = (attributes.flags & WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE)
                == WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE;
        boolean expectedSecureState = isShowingIncognito();
        if (currentSecureState == expectedSecureState) return;

        if (expectedSecureState) {
            mWindow.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE);
        } else {
            mWindow.clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE);
        }
    }
```

<sup>Source: [chrome/android/java/src/org/chromium/chrome/browser/incognito/IncognitoTabSnapshotController.java](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/8e084f697e8acfe1d1752dee702d8d73eb9655b0/chrome/android/java/src/org/chromium/chrome/browser/incognito/IncognitoTabSnapshotController.java)</sup>

This is imposing rules you can expect to have in a enterprise environment on a personal phone.

> The operation system UI should make clear when and how other apps are recording the screen. As an app developer, I should not be bothered with avoiding screen captures. Breaking this functionality breaks the lowest common denominator of data sharing: Taking a screenshot. One of the reason to make a screenshot is just because an application misses a proper data export functionality.

Source: [HN Discussion](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=16572761)

> [image]

Is there any way to disable or prevent this behavior?

Comment: That could be due to your device admin policy (if you are on a corporate device or allowed your company as a device admin). Did this start happening from the browser upgrade?

Comment: Related: [Disable Screenshot security](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/133022/209414)

Comment: Surely the point of doing this is to prevent you accidentally leaving evidence of what you did in incognito mode?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Update:**

1. Navigate to `chrome://flags`

   [image]
2. Search for "Incognito Screenshot" and mark and mark the `incognito-screenshot` as **Enabled**

   [image]
3. Restart Chrome

---

**Previous workaround:**

For now, the workaround to take screenshots in Incognito mode is the following:

1. Navigate to `chrome://flags`
2. Search for "share-screenshot" and mark the `chrome-share-screenshot` as **Enabled**

   [image]
3. Restart Chrome
4. Open Incognito mode, click the share button below the address bar

   [image]
5. Select **Screenshot** and then **Save**

   [image]

Comment: Nice to know! Might want to also mention the Chrome version if possible for historical purpose.

Answer (score 6):

This appears to be a side-effect [hiding incognito tabs from the recent apps list](https://chromium-review.googlesource.com/c/chromium/src/+/809508), which is intended as a privacy feature.

They also added an `--enable-incognito-snapshots-in-android-recents` switch to change this behavior, but unfortunately that's not easy to pass on Android, and there isn't an entry in `chrome://flags`. I didn't find anyone requesting a way to make it (easily) optional; I suggest filing a bug report about the screenshot-blocking side effect; that switch should at least be exposed as a flag.

Comment: This isn't a side-effect, the implementation was in Canary months ago and landed in stable 65. As far as I know there's no effort to fix this behavior.

Comment: @MatijaGrcic I don't think there is a way to block it from appearing in the recent apps list w/o blocking screenshots; that's an Android limitation (one flag controls both), so Chrome can't fix that. They wanted the former; the later comes with it, hence a side-effect.  You're correct, though, that 65 is released; I'll fix that. I couldn't find any bug about the inability to disable it; do you have a pointer to one? Or has no one asked?

Comment: I've filed a [feature request](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=920762) to add the flag to chrome://flags. Please star it to get it fixed more quickly.

Comment: @ThomasOrlita The status of the request is now **WontFix (Closed)**. How nice of them!